# How could I get docs while typing a method in IntelliJ? Not after

Tags: intellij-idea

Here is what happend in Eclipse. When I am typing a method, I could know the docs.
[image: in Eclipse]

Comment: To increase the quality of your question, please use the "insert image" option of the editor while posting it. (see my answer below for example). This will inline the image and makes it easier to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invoke the `quick documentation` action. On mac it's F1 or CTRL+J. Look it up in settings -> keymap to find and/or assign keyboard shortcut for this action.

The details in the rectangular are shown after the action is invoked.

[image: Screenshot of result]

It's also possible to show the quick documentation when moving the mouse cursor on a method. If you want that, go to `settings -> editor -> general` and check the option `Show quick documentation on mouse move` and specify the delay you prefer.